# Why didn't my edit get transferred over with my question?

Tags: support, edits, migration, migrated-questions

from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561780/easy-way-to-transfer-a-private-key-to-another-machine?noredirect=1

to here:

[Easy way to transfer a private key to another machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/340501/easy-way-to-transfer-a-private-key-to-another-machine)

I made the edit before the question was transferred: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7561780/revisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did transfer.

Then [slhck edited it out.](https://superuser.com/posts/340501/revisions)

Comment: ah okay, didn't think to check that... hah.